The microphone of the wired headset does not work (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS)
After installing the operating system, I saw that the built-in microphone and speakers of the laptop were working well, plugged in the monitor - the sound worked well... connected a Bluetooth headset - the microphone and sound were working well. I connect a wired headset ... the sound is there, but the microphone does not work.
In the settings, the microphone is displayed but not active. And application like Skype don't  work!  On previous version of Ubuntu 22.04 all  work from box.
Who can help to repair it?
